# Extracting data from paginated nested links

Tags: pagination, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrapy

I have a paginated list of IMDb titles of about 17 pages: [the list](http://www.imdb.com/search/title?count=250&num_votes=30000,&sort=num_votes,desc&view=simple)

The link has URLs in the form of http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0111161/?ref_=adv_li_tt

Where **tt0111161** is the title ID.

I'd like to go through the whole list, and for each title, go to the URL http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0111161/ratings 
 and extract HTML info from that page. How can I do that with Scrapy, BeautifulSoup, or any other method?

Comment: What do you want to extra from 'http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0111161/ratings '?

Comment: @PiyushS.Wanare The votes distribution.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have any code to share with issues you are seeing while running it?

Comment: @paultrmbrth I don't know where to start yet, so I still haven't written code for it.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this way:-

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib
r = urllib.urlopen('http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0111161/ratings').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(r)
print soup
```

**NOTE -** IMDb will not allow you to scrap their website.

Comment: Ok, that could download the ratings page, thanks. But I need a way to get the ratings page for each title in the list. How to do that?

Comment: Check if IMdb has any API else they have security we can't scrap that.

Comment: I did check, they don't have an API, all they have is a dump of text files that are messy and hard to parse, so this is the only way to go. What do you mean by "they have security"?

Comment: Many website while developing will secure their web page so whatever the data they have on website should not able to scrap by any one.

Comment: If my answer looks helpful for you  then you can accept and up vote it.

Comment: Yeah, but I can scrape IMDb pages with no problems, just need to automate it for all the titles in a list, that's all.